# PINE script iteration with manual drawing

Tags: pine-script

Is somehow possible manually create some objects in TV - for example supply zone-and then get info about those (high and low of zone) to PINE to work with them?

Or if I want these data I have just two possibilities?:

- create whole process / also drawing those as automatic
- create multiple user inputs and put info about those zones over there?

Any advice appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pinescript does not have access to user drawn objects.

The possibilities you listed are your only options.